# how can I retrieve correct routes for rest resources?

Tags: 8, services

I installed drupal 8 on my local server.
I enabled all web services modules and installed rest ui module.
I enabled some rest resources, such as entity/menu.
Now, I need to know how to get correct routes for entities.
For example, I tried to get main menu information by requesting http://localhost/mysite/entity/menu/main?_format=hal_json, but I received response 401.
So, there is a way to get a list of available routes for my rest server?

Comment: It's probably overkill, but the [OpenAPI module](https://www.drupal.org/project/openapi) (and its add-ons) would get you that information. Plus allow you to test your APIs in the browser